# munit throw a specific exception

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, munit

I am trying to throw a Filter Unaccepted Exception in munit to test my error handling but I am getting this error

```
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Failed to invoke throw-an.
at get_data_filter_unaccepted_exception-test.mock:throw-an{doc:name=Throw unaccepted Exception, exception-ref=#[new org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException()], whenCalling=.*:.*}(get_data_from_qcfc-test-suite.xml:316)
at appleFlow.munit:test{initialState=started, description=Test, ignore=false, abstract=false, id=MunitTestFlow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$904837f0{get_data_filter_unaccepted_exception-test}}(get_data_from_qcfc-test-suite.xml:315)
Caused by: org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: Execution of the expression "new org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException()" failed.
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluateInternal(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:232)
```

This is my throw an exception

```
<mock:when messageProcessor=".*:.*" doc:name="Mock API Token Web Service Call">
        <mock:with-attributes>
            <mock:with-attribute name="doc:name" whereValue="#['Get API Token']"/>
        </mock:with-attributes>
        <mock:then-return payload="#[getResource('api_token_success.xml').asString()]" mimeType="application/xml"/>

    </mock:when>
```

I think it is because of my MEL statement

```
#[new org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a groovy component to throw your exception like that

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Throw Exception">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[throw new org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException(); ]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
```

Hope it helps.

/T

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `throw-an` call in the snippet you pasted.

Anyways, No argument constructor for `org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException` is not public, try using `#[new org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException('Some message')]`